# Java 8 stream map on entry set

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I'm trying to perform a map operation on each entry in a `Map` object.

I need to take a prefix off the key and convert the value from one type to another. My code is taking configuration entries from a `Map<String, String>` and converting to a `Map<String, AttributeType>` (`AttributeType` is just a class holding some information. Further explanation is not relevant for this question.)

The best I have been able to come up with using the Java 8 Streams is the following:

```
private Map<String, AttributeType> mapConfig(Map<String, String> input, String prefix) {
   int subLength = prefix.length();
   return input.entrySet().stream().flatMap((Map.Entry<String, Object> e) -> {
      HashMap<String, AttributeType> r = new HashMap<>();
      r.put(e.getKey().substring(subLength), AttributeType.GetByName(e.getValue()));
      return r.entrySet().stream();
   }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

Being unable to construct an `Map.Entry` due to it being an interface causes the creation of the single entry `Map` instance and the use of `flatMap()`, which seems ugly.

Is there a better alternative? It seems nicer to do this using a for loop:

```
private Map<String, AttributeType> mapConfig(Map<String, String> input, String prefix) {
   Map<String, AttributeType> result = new HashMap<>(); 
   int subLength = prefix.length(); 
   for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : input.entrySet()) {
      result.put(entry.getKey().substring(subLength), AttributeType.GetByName( entry.getValue()));
   }
   return result;
}
```

Should I avoid the Stream API for this? Or is there a nicer way I have missed?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Simply translating the "old for loop way" into streams:

```
private Map<String, String> mapConfig(Map<String, Integer> input, String prefix) {
    int subLength = prefix.length();
    return input.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                   entry -> entry.getKey().substring(subLength), 
                   entry -> AttributeType.GetByName(entry.getValue())));
}
```

Answer (score 37):

Please make the following part of the Collectors API:

```
<K, V> Collector<? super Map.Entry<K, V>, ?, Map<K, V>> toMap() {
  return Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue);
}
```

Comment: While I generally agree, there need to be a normal way to instantiate the entry interface first. If not, it'll be of no use :-(

Comment: @thoredge It would still be extremely useful on entries obtained directly from another map, e.g.: `map.entrySet().stream().filter(...).collect(toMap())`.

Comment: `.map(store -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(item1, item2))`
Should have a simple static factory method, like: `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.of(item1, item2)`
and you static import the `of(` and done, its easy.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this a request for a Java API improvement masquerading as a Stack Overflow answer?  It doesn't even seem to answer the question.

Answer (score 30):

Question might be a little dated, but you could simply use AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<> as follows:

```
private Map<String, AttributeType> mapConfig(
    Map<String, String> input, String prefix) {
       int subLength = prefix.length();
       return input.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
               e.getKey().substring(subLength),
               AttributeType.GetByName(e.getValue()))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

any other Pair-like value object would work too (ie. ApacheCommons Pair tuple).

Answer (score 10):

On Java 9 or later, [`Map.entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) can be used, so long as you know that neither the key nor value will be null.  If either value could legitimately be null, [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) (as suggested in another answer) or [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html) are good alternatives.

```java
private Map<String, AttributeType> mapConfig(Map<String, String> input, String prefix) {
   int subLength = prefix.length();
   return input.entrySet().stream().map(e -> 
      Map.entry(e.getKey().substring(subLength), AttributeType.GetByName(e.getValue()))
   ).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

That being said, in this particular case, there's no real value in the interim `Entry` object, and it would be more idiomatic to perform the key/value mapping within `Collectors.toMap` (as demonstrated in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27229114/1108305)).  However, there are legitimate reasons to create interim entry objects, so it's still helpful to know.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using the built-in Java stream support, the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library could be used.  It has fluent support for streams of `Entry` objects by way of the [`EntryStream`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html) class:

```java
private Map<String, String> mapConfig(Map<String, Integer> input, String prefix) {
    int subLength = prefix.length();
    return EntryStream.of(input)
            .mapKeys(key -> key.substring(subLength))
            .mapValues(AttributeType::GetByName)
            .toMap();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a shorter solution by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Stream.of(input).toMap(e -> e.getKey().substring(subLength), 
                       e -> AttributeType.GetByName(e.getValue()));
```

Comment: How can this work? Stream.of is for either singletons or arrays (can be vararg), but not as far as I can see for Maps, by any stretch.

Comment: There's Stream class included in the abacus-util library. Not the one in jdk